# Active Record: Users who have not created Events since X date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This is probably quite simple but i'm having a little trouble getting this right.

I have a User model and Event model. Both have the usual created_at attribute. Users can have many events and an event belongs to a user.

What want to do is write something in active record to give me all users that have not created an event since a given date.

I have managed to do it with multiple loops but it's highly inefficient. Is it possible to do this efficiently with one statement or perhaps a named scope?

I have a named scope to count events by users:

```
  scope :user_event_count,
      select("users.id, count(events.id) AS events_count").
      joins(:events).
      group("users.id").
      order("events_count DESC")
```

I'm wondering if similar is possible, but am having trouble working out how to find the last event a user submitted.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a break up about how to achieve this.

1. Select all users for all events that were created since a given date
2. Select all users who are not in the above set

```
subquery = Event.select("user_id").where("created_at >= :start_date", {start_date: params[:start_date]}).to_sql;
User.where("id NOT IN (#{subquery})")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very cool. Works well, but also gives me users who have never created an event. I'm basically after users who once created but haven't for some time. I'm sure I can figure it out based on your answer though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is the users for whom the maximum event creation date is prior to some time.

```
scope :user_event_count,
      select("users.id, max(events.created_at) AS max_event_created_at").
      joins(:events).
      group("users.id").
      having("max(events.created_at) < :start_date")
```

If you had a very large number of events it might be more efficient to structure it as a query where there exists an event prior to a particular time and there does not exist an event since that time.